# send file from node to client for download

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am using an ajax call from browser
so, on button click 
a function is called
for route '/file'

```
app.get('/filez',function(req,res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('id is : ',id);

  var video =   ytdl(url, { filter: (format) => format.container === 'mp4' })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp4'));
    res.download('video.mp4');
```

now, the file is being downloaded to the server at the moment.
but what I want to do is to send the file so the client can download it from browser.
i dont want the file to be downloaded to the server.

Here's the ajax request I made from the browser using a button click.
and I want to get the file as the response which can be downloaded to the client computer.

```
function myAjaxCall(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState ===XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status ===200){
            console.log('response has come',xhr.response);
            return xhr.response;
        }
    };
    xhr.open('GET','/filez',true);
    xhr.send();
};
```

EXPLANATION : well, not really. i was thinking more along these lines - so on button click an ajax call is sent to server and it's supposed to get back a response. I want the file to be sent via this response.
so, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about this, but I assume files for download, especially big files are stored in Storage bucket with static urls. You can get the item from that storage bucket and send the link to the client, which prompts the download. Some examples AWS S3, Firebase Storage, Azure Blob etc.

Answer (score 0):

pass the get request in a href tag and it will download the file to the client , you are writing the file in server side so it is being created their , you have to have the file been created on the server side and then serve the file through res.download to the client side and later delete the file from the server side to download the file in clinet side 
suppose your url looks like http://getsomefile.com/xyz?newfile=video.mp4 then in your client sides a tag you can have this url as on some domain http://getsomefile.com with route xyz to serve the file

`<a href="http://getsomefile.com/xyz?newfile=video.mp4" download>`

where i am assuming on client side you have some route defined as

```
  app.get('/xyz,function(req,res){
         var file = req.query.newfile;

        })
```

and then you can use fs.unlink to delete the files through a cron like or have a manual cleaner used  or do something like this

```
 app.get('/xyz', function(req, res){
     var file = req.query.newfile
        res.download(realFilepath, file , function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                fs.unlink(realFilepath);
            }
        });
    });
```

realFilepath is the actual path of file kept in server , which you can gracefully delete after the file has been served.

Comment: well, not really.
i was thinking more along these lines
- so on button click an ajax call is sent to server
and it's supposed to get back a response.
I want the file to be sent via this response.